# Problem with transitive dependency while using BOM

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-bom

Lets say I have
1. a bom project(named as bom)
2. a jar project(named as A)
3. a war project(named as B)

bom project has jackson-data version as 2.8.5 and 2.8.1 in properties and in dependencymanagement section 2.8.5 for jackson-data.

project A which inherits bom declares jackson-data dependency in it with version 2.8.1.

project B depends on project A and inherits bom. it does not declare the jackson-data in its dependency

now when I look at lib dir of Project B, jackson-data version  is 2.8.5 where as project A is declaring it as 2.8.1.

irrespective of what is declared in dependency it is taking the version declared in bom. is there any way to resolve the transitive dependency of jackson-data in project B as it is declared in project A means a version of 2.8.1 and not 2.8.5 while using the bom?

Below are the poms

BOM PROJECT

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
    instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>bom</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.8.5</jackson-databind.version>
    <jackson-databind.version.A>2.8.1</jackson-databind.version.A>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

### pom of project A

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Project B

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.emirates.ibe</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>B</warName>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

DependencyManagement overrides transitive dependencies. This is what happens here (and this is how it's meant to be).

If you want a different version, either change the dependencyManagement or override in the project in which you use A

Comment: understand this is how maven was implemented.but is there any other way to override this feature?

Comment: I offered you two. What don't you like about them?

Comment: We are working on segregating a big monolith application into small self contained projects(currently 200+ projects are there). all of them have a common bom. and all this projects are interdependent(now we are resolving through nexus). as it is a legacy application, different project uses different versions of the same thirdparty libs and they works fine. <br> now if change dependencyManagement to i.e I am enforcing the projects to use same version of the thirdparty app(they may fail with that). if we are overriding the pom, I will have go to check all transitive deps and modify poms.

Comment: So, I was looking for a way which will enable me to override the default behavior of maven and transitive dependencies will not get overridden by bom.  This will ensure that we are not breaking the existing code and at the same time we have segregated the project as part of first phase. Your answer is perfect for our second phase initiative where we will force developers to use same version or override in their projects as per there needs

Comment: This is not possible. If you don't want dependencyManagement in place, you need to delete it from the `com.test:bom` parent POM. Your parent POM essentially says: "Override the transitive versions", so if you don't want that, remove it from the parent POM.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for taking time to review and answer the question. cheers